# How to avoid Repeated input by the user

Tags: python, input, while-loop

how to make sure the same input is not repeated in python in a while loop
explanation -I want to check if a user has already given the same input and if so tell it the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Add the input to a set and afterwards check if the set already contains the current input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but you can try this:

```
given_inputs = []

while True:
    x = input('>')
    if x not in given_inputs:
        given_inputs.append(x)
        print('New Input!')
    else:
        print('Input not valid')
```